# Extracting row and column from data frame in R

Tags: r, text-processing, data-extraction

I have a csv file from which i would like to extract second column values into a data frame the example csv file looks like the image below

[image]

Following is the script that i written

```
ICVdir <- "/media/dev/Daten/Task1/T1_Images"
#loding csv file from ICV
mycsv  <- list.files(ICVdir,pattern = "*.csv",full.names = T )
af<- read.csv(file = mycsv,header = TRUE, sep = "\t")
ICV<- as.data.frame(af[,2],drop=FALSE)
```

The output of data.frame `af` is :

```
 subj_id.eTIV_FLIRT.FASTvol_noCSF
1             Sub1,0.824198,1360784
2             Sub2,0.792987,1350024
3             Sub3,0.831011,1304154
4             Sub4,0.840316,1277706
5             Sub5,0.928503,1562892
6             Sub6,0.840962,1367487
7             Sub7,0.776565,1486331
8             Sub8,0.845449,1394665
9             Sub9,0.924351,1496015
10           Sub10,0.885719,1450941
11       Mean eTIV_FLIRT,0.8490061,
```

I would like to extract the values in column eTIV_FLIRT( which is second column into a data frame

I am obtaining following output

```
 Error in `[.data.frame`(af, , 2) : undefined columns selected
```

kindly please let me know what is wrong in my code

Comment: Try changing the last line to `ICV <- af[, 2, drop = FALSE]`.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik   This is the error i am getting : Error in `[.data.frame`(af, , 2, drop = FALSE) : 
  undefined columns selected

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a [reproducible problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). In particular, we do not have your CSV file.

Comment: And please do not post images of text. That makes reproducing your problem not easier - do you expect us to re-type your data? Additionally, the screen shot does not show the actual file contents (which seems to be your problem, if my answer is correct). Finally, images take up bandwidth and make the page load slower.

Comment: What is the exact code you're using? Please show at least `str(af)` of your dataset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code

```
af<- read.csv(file = mycsv,header = TRUE, sep = "\t")
```

you specify a tab as the separator.
Your data.frame contains only *one* column. E.g., the first row is the single value `Sub1,0.824198,1360784`.

As you have only one column, you cannot extract the second with `af[,2]`.

Simply removing the `sep` (leaving the default comma) should solve your problem.

Comment: How can i extract the first value in new data frame ICV ?

Comment: Depends on what you define as the "first value". It even more depends on what you actually want to achieve. Generally, `df[i, j]` returns the value of the `i`ths row in the `j`th column. — But please do not distract from the original question. If you have a new question, ask a new question. Of course, please make sure it hasn't asked before, and you [ask properly](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).